# How to format a memory card which is infected by a virus and antivirus is not able to delete it

Tags: virus, anti-virus, format, memory-card

I've bought a memory card which is recently infected by a virus. I tried to scan it with latest Bitdefender 2014 and Norton 2014 they both failed to delete the virus. Then I deleted the partition and created a new partition in gparted for Linux, but the virus remains.

Please advice me on how to remove the virus from the memory card.

Comment: If you deleted the partition and the virus came back, its the actual computer your using to access the storage device, that is infecting it.

Comment: What do you mean by this ?

" Then I deleted the partition and created a new partition in gparted for Linux, but the virus remains."

What do you think is the virus in ur pc ?

Comment: I second Ramhound.
If you've cleared *properly* your card, then the only option left is your PC that reinfects it (or a quite sophisticated virus).

Comment: If your anti-viruses cannot find this virus, what makes you so sure there is one ? It cannot survive deletion of partition, thus either the is no virus or you computer is infected, as explained by the others.

Answer (score 7):

This probably happens because your computer is infected. You might delete it but then your computer is going to re-infect it again.

My vote goes to use a linux machine to format it, since it doesn't execute code upon plugging the flash drive. Then clean your computer before plugging it and infecting it again!!

If on the other hand your machine is already linux, clean the machine first with the card away and then clean the card.

Comment: No my computer is perfect I've tried in fresh linux ubuntu and kali linux but no use

Comment: @AnirudhPulikonda What exactly did you try from Linux?

Comment: i tried to format it using the "disks" software but no use

Answer (score 1):

when you boot in linux, go to the console.

determine the device by using the command: fdisk -l

then zero your out your memory card

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb (assuming that sdb is your memory card)

Answer (score 0):

Paranoid mode: Get a Linux LiveCD after checking the MD5 sum, disconnect the hard drive cable inside the PC's case, unhook the Ethernet cable, disconnect the USB Wi-Fi radio or flip the mechanical switch to turn the wireless off, then use the terminal with dd to zero out the memory card. Do it with /dev/urandom then re-boot to the Live CD again, then do it with /dev/zero again. Then make ABSOLUTELY SURE the target PC you are using the memory card on is virus free.

In the old days I had to use a rare-earth magnet on floppy disks to make sure the viruses were gone.